# Unable to update text , on click of a event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a plus and a minus button:

```
<div class="col">
    <i class="minus"></i>
    <i class="qt">1</i>
    <i class="plus"></i>
</div>
```

On a click of the plus button, I want to increase the quantity and similarly decrease the quantity, when the minus button is clicked.

In order to realize this I have written two events:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".minus", function() {
   var quantity = $(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text();
   var a = parseInt(quantity);
   a-=1; 
   $(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text-a;    
});

$( document ).on( "click", ".plus", function() {
   var quantity = $(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text();
   var a = parseInt(quantity);
   a+=1; 
   $(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text+a;
});
```

However, unimportant of what button is pressed, nothing happens.

Could you please help?

A fiddle showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/LESn3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.next()` and `prev()` to target the quantity text:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".minus", function() {
  var quantity = $(this).next().text(parseInt($(this).next().text())-1);
});
$( document ).on( "click", ".plus", function() {
  var quantity = $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text())+1);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BHWgQ/)**

Comment: and similarly in case i  need to updated the quantity , why this is not working ?? $(this).closest("ul").find("div.price").text()*quantity;

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the text value back correctly.

You need to call .text as a function:

```
$(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text(a);
```

Fixed example - http://jsfiddle.net/LESn3/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually updating the text

It'll work if you replace the lines:

```
$(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text-a;
// ...
$(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text+a;
```

with:

```
$(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the OP, here is the solution you should be looking at.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".minus,.plus", function() {
    var quantity = $(this).siblings('.qt').text();
    var a = parseInt(quantity);
    if($(this).hasClass('minus'))
        a-=1;
    else
        a+=1; 
    $(this).siblings('.qt').text(a);    
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/nzJQn/)**