# on a class click event text is being wrongly updated

Tags: jquery

Assume a Shopping Cart Website , and if an Item is selected , 
I am showing the plus  minus button , quantity  and the Amount .

On click of the plus button , i am updating the quantity and the Amount , as shown below

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function () {
  $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text()) + 1);
  var price = parseInt($(this).closest("ul").find("div.price").text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text());
  $(this).closest("ul").find("div.price").text(price + price);
});
```

I am observing the Amount is calculating wrongly , it is being based on its previous value .

```
 <li class="prd-items-qt">
    <div class="col">
        <i class="minus"></i>
        <i class="qt">1</i>
        <i class="plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="price">
        150
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to update text , on click of a event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951481/unable-to-update-text-on-click-of-a-event)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `closest("li")` and not `closest("ul")`

You are going too far back up the tree and finding the first match in the list, rather than the individual line-item.

Also, stop wasting jQuery cycles in selectors (by adding  temp variables):

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $prev = $this.prev();
    var $li = $this.closest('li');
    $prev.text(parseInt($prev.text()) + 1);
    var price = parseInt($li.find("div.price").text());
    var quantity = parseInt($li.find("i.qt").text());
    $li.find("div.price").text(price + price);
});
```

*This tends to make the code easier to read too :)*

Note You probably wanted:

```
$li.find("div.price").text(price * quantity);
```

`Rory McCrossan` has gone to the trouble of cleaning up the code even further in his answer, so suggest you follow his guide for readability :)

Answer (score 2):

Your logic for calculating price is incorrect, as you are multiplying quantity by the calculated prices, so it will be `150, 300, 600, 1200, 2400` and so on, instead of `150, 300, 450, 600`.

You can use a `data-*` attribute to store the unit price to be multiplied. Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function () {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.prd-items-qt');
    var $quantity = $container.find('.qt');
    var $unitPrice = $container.find('div.price');
    var quantity = parseInt($quantity.text(), 10) + 1;
    var unitPrice = parseInt($unitPrice.data('unit-price'), 10);  
    $quantity.text(quantity);
    $unitPrice.text(quantity * unitPrice);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qVJy8/3/)

Comment: Thanks , Getting NAN ----

Comment: Is your HTML structure different to your example in the question?

Comment: +1 for spotting the additional problems without much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a total column. As you are doubling the previous price each time you increase quantity. Instead you want to do price * quantity:

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function () {
  var li = $(this).closest("li");
  $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text()) + 1);
  var price = parseInt(li.find("div.price").text());
  var quantity = parseInt(li.find("i.qt").text());

  li.find("div.total").text(price * quantity);
});
```

Also, you can select the `ul` once and then reuse than instead of finding it each time you need to access a child on it.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/5Ghp2/

Comment: `UL` contains all the lines items, so this is still going too high up the tree. It needs to stop at `li` (or `.prd-items-qt`)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I agree that is likely but it's possible the OP has a UL per item row. It's impossible to tell from his example. (But I will update just to be clear)

Comment: I read "it is being based on its previous value" as meaning from a previous line item (which would occur with his code if there were multiple LI/line items).

Comment: I am sorry i am  working on all the options provided above  , nothing has worked   so couldn't update , this is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AS8u5/

Comment: strangely everything is working fine in the alert alert(price * quantity); but not at li.find("div.price").text(price * quantity);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for `closest('li')` instead of `closest('ul')` as `li` is there in the upper hierarchy of clicked element and not `ul` :

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function () {
  $(this).prev().text(parseInt($(this).prev().text()) + 1);
  var price = parseInt($(this).closest("li").find("div.price").text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).closest("li").find("i.qt").text());
  $(this).closest("li").find("div.price").text(price + price);
});
```

You can write same code in more readable way so that it will be easy to debug:

```
$(document).on("click", ".plus", function () {
   var $quantityLi = $(this).prev();
    var quantity = parseInt($quantityLi.text());
    quantity+=1;

    $quantityLi.text(quantity);

    var $priceDiv = $(this).closest('li').find('.price');
    var price = parseInt($priceDiv.text());

    var totalPrice = price * quantity;
    $priceDiv.text(price+totalPrice);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/240/)